# Arguments are invalid in octave program (similar to matlab)

Tags: c#, matlab

Good Morning!

I'm having problems with lines 9 and 13. The error message is saying that the arguments are invalid.

Can anyone help me activate this working code?

-ERRO EXEMPLE-
error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 0x0)
error: called from
teste4 at line 9 column 7

-FULL CODE-

```
    x=input('Informe o vetor x ([x1,x2,...,xn]):'); %[2 3 4]
    p=input('Informe o ponto de estudo (xn):'); %3
    i=find(x==p); %Encontra a posição de p em x
    %***********************************************

    f=@(x)(x^3);   %Definindo a função de estudo
    g=diff(sym(f));clc; %Converte para symbolic e deriva
    df=matlabFunction(g); %Def. deriv. de f.
    der(1)=df(x(i)); %Sol. exata analítica

    %**************************************************

    dp=(f(x(i+1))- f(x(i)))/(x(i+1)-x(i));      % Progressiva
    dr=(f(x(i))  - f(x(i-1)))/(x(i)-x(i-1));   % Regressiva
    dc=(f(x(i+1))- f(x(i-1)))/(x(i+1)-x(i-1)); % Central
    der=[der dp dr dc];
    for i=2:4
    E_r(i) = abs((der(i)-der(1))/der(1));     % Erros
    end
    %**************************************************

    Sol=[der' E_r']
    printf("O valor da difexata é exata é %.2f.\n", der(1))
    printf("O valor da dif. progressiva é %.2f com erro de %.3f.\n",          dp, E_r(2))
    printf("O valor da dif. regressiva é %.2f com erro de %.3f.\n", dr, E_r(3))
    printf("O valor da dif. central é %.2f com erro de %.3f.\n", dc, E_r(4))
```

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: @Danizavtz no caso aqui a imagem não ajuda, é o caso de deixar só em texto mesmo. Mas de qualquer forma o autor já foi instruido, essa pergunta aqui é repetida. É o caso de fazer os ajustes na original.

Comment: Para evitar duplicidade de orientações, travei os comentários aqui, mas o assunto pode ser tratado na postagem original - comentários inclusive. Acesse a original e clique em "editar" para fazer as adequações - aí ela entra automaticamente num sistema de reavaliação). Segue link: [AUXÍLIO EM CÓDIGO DO OCTAVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/543928/70)